# function compare with variable in mysql

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php $check=$ word[ 'Word'][ 'en_words']; ?>
<form id="" method="post" action="">
    <label>
        <span id="first"><?= $check; ?></span>
        <span>EN:</span>
        <input type="text" id="second" />
    </label>
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Check" onclick="validate()" />
    <script>
    function validate() {
        var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
        var second = document.getElementById('second').value;
        if (second == first) {
            alert('Ok!');
        } else {
            alert('No!');
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Why this script doesn't work, could someone see?
I want compare variable with input to $check (mysql record).

Comment: There is no MySQL or any other SQL here. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't told us what the expected result is.

Anyway, I see that you use a `document.getElementById('first').value` on a ''. This funcion only works with form elements.

You should use something like: `document.getElementById('first').innerHTML`. So, your code should look like:

```
....
<script>
        function validate(){
        var first = document.getElementById('first').innerHTML;
        var second = document.getElementById('second').value;
                    if (second == first){
                            alert('Ok!');
                    }
                    else {
                            alert('No!');
                    }
                    }

 </script>
```

Comment: The first one should be  `var first = document.getElementById('first').innerHTML;` or `var first = document.getElementById('first').textContent;` and the second one `var second = document.getElementById('second').value`. One of them is an `input` element! Also note that `value` is not a function.

Comment: var first always = first element table Word

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the $check variable is being printed.  You may need to echo or print the variable:

```
<span id="first"><?php print $check; ?></span>
```

Also, the span element does not contain a value.  Instead, try capturing the value with innerHTML:

```
var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since first is html tag so it will have innerHtml and second is input so it will have value

```
<script>
        function validate(){
    var first = document.getElementById('first').innerHTML;
    var second = document.getElementById('second').value;
                if (second == first){
                        alert('Ok!');
                }
                else {
                        alert('No!');
                }
                }

 </script>

<button onclick="validate()">Click</button>
```

Comment: when you enter some value in second input field it would not be empty... trigger this function on click of button after entering the value in input field it would show you result

Comment: <button onclick="validate()">Click</button>